# Trying to adjust margins and csquote is not working

Tags: margins, csquotes

I am trying to use [wuthesis template](https://computing.artsci.wustl.edu/latex-style-files) to write my dissertation, but I am having trouble with the margins. The top margins are very large and the bottom margins are cutting off the page numbers. Also, I can't seem to get csquote to work. I spent 12 hours trying to figure it out yesterday with no success. Of course the cls file is huge, so I attached the link below. I appreciate your help!

```
\documentclass{umslthesis}

% Put your thesis title below.
%
\title{A Nation Divided: Assessing the Regional Effects of Institutional Capacity, Social Capital, and Civic Culture on Tax Morale in Italy}

% Put your name here.
% First one is the name you want to put on the cover.
% Second is the one you want to use in abstract.
\author{John D'Attoma}{D'Attoma, John}

% Put your Degree here.
% First is long title of degree (used on cover).
% Second is abbreviation for degree (used in abstract).
% Third is the month the degree was (will be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% Last is the year the degree was (wlll be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% The degree title for all doctoral candidates is ``Doctor of Philosophy.''
\wudegree{Doctor of Philosophy}{Ph.D.}{December}{2015}

% Put your advisor's name here.
\majorprof{Dr. Joyce Mushaben}

% List the names of the members of the committee here.
\committee{Dr. Joyce Mushaben, Chair\\Dr. Kenneth Thomas, Co-chair\\Dr. David Kimball\\Dr. Fred Cocozzelli}

% You may put your own abbreviation here.
\input{mydefs}

\begin{document}

\volume

\include{front}
\include{ch01}
\include{ch02}
\include{ch03}
\include{ch04}
\include{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you are trying to do in your tex file.  Presumably the margins are fixed to meet the university's standards and are not intended to be changed.  `csquotes` appears to work perfectly well with this: just put `\usepackage{csquotes}` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I have copied my tex file above.Thanks for the csquote help; I had it in the wrong place. Also thanks for helping out a newby with some very basic questions.

Comment: The link you've provided does not appear to lead to a file named `umslthesis.cls`. Please check if you provided the correct link.

Comment: I can't test `csquotes`, as you don't seem to be loading it and an example is missing.

Comment: sorry, if you replace umslthesis.cls with wuthesis.cls, it should match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class works well with `latex`, as opposed to `pdflatex`; try doing

```
\documentclass{umslthesis}
% set the pdf dimensions
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
% set the correct origin
\setlength{\pdfvorigin}{0pt}

% Put your thesis title below.
%
\title{A Nation Divided: Assessing the Regional Effects of Institutional Capacity, Social Capital, and Civic Culture on Tax Morale in Italy}

% Put your name here.
% First one is the name you want to put on the cover.
% Second is the one you want to use in abstract.
\author{John D'Attoma}{D'Attoma, John}

% Put your Degree here.
% First is long title of degree (used on cover).
% Second is abbreviation for degree (used in abstract).
% Third is the month the degree was (will be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% Last is the year the degree was (wlll be) awarded (used on cover
% and abstract).
% The degree title for all doctoral candidates is ``Doctor of Philosophy.''
\wudegree{Doctor of Philosophy}{Ph.D.}{December}{2015}

% Put your advisor's name here.
\majorprof{Dr. Joyce Mushaben}

% List the names of the members of the committee here.
\committee{Dr. Joyce Mushaben, Chair\\Dr. Kenneth Thomas, Co-chair\\Dr. David Kimball\\Dr. Fred Cocozzelli}

% You may put your own abbreviation here.
\input{mydefs}

\begin{document}

<... the rest of your document ...>
```

The placement of the text block should be the desired one.